# Opendaylight Boron : Config Shard not getting created and Circuit Breaker Timed out

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

We are using ODL Boron - SR2. We observe a strange behavior of "Config" Shard not getting created when we start ODL in cluster mode in RHEL 6.9. We observe Circuit Breaker Timed Out exception. However "Operational" shard is getting created without any issues. Due to unavailability of "Config" shard we are unable to persist anything in "Config" tree. We checked in JMX console and "Shards" is missing.

This is consistently reproducible in RHEL, however it works in CentOS.

```
2018-04-04 08:00:38,396 | WARN  | saction-29-31'}}  | 168 - org.opendaylight.controller.config-manager - 0.5.2.Boron-SR2 | DeadlockMonitor$DeadlockMonitorRunnable | ModuleIdentifier{factoryName='runtime-generated-mapping', instanceName='runtime-mapping-singleton'} did not finish after 26697 ms
2018-04-04 08:00:38,396 | WARN  | saction-29-31'}}  | 168 - org.opendaylight.controller.config-manager - 0.5.2.Boron-SR2 | DeadlockMonitor$DeadlockMonitorRunnable | ModuleIdentifier{factoryName='runtime-generated-mapping', instanceName='runtime-mapping-singleton'} did not finish after 26697 ms
2018-04-04 08:00:40,690 | ERROR | lt-dispatcher-30  | 216 - com.typesafe.akka.slf4j - 2.4.7 | Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1 | Failed to persist event type [org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.raft.persisted.UpdateElectionTerm] with sequence number [4] for persistenceId [member-2-shard-default-config].
akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker$$anon$1: Circuit Breaker Timed out.
2018-04-04 08:00:40,690 | ERROR | lt-dispatcher-30  | 216 - com.typesafe.akka.slf4j - 2.4.7 | Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1 | Failed to persist event type [org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.raft.persisted.UpdateElectionTerm] with sequence number [4] for persistenceId [member-2-shard-default-config].
akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker$$anon$1: Circuit Breaker Timed out.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with akka persistence where it times out trying to write to the disk. See the discussion in https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/controller-dev/2017-August/013781.html.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the prompt answer. akka.conf has following entries

 persistence {
      journal.plugin = akka.persistence.journal.leveldb
      snapshot-store.plugin = akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local
    }
Do i need to modify like this
circuit-breaker {
        max-failures = 10
        call-timeout = 10s
        reset-timeout = 30s
      }

Comment: Tom, I tried changing akka.conf with circuit-breaker entries, but still it is failing.

Comment: I assume you tried increasing the call-timeout and it still failed. Of course 10s is a long time anyway and I assume the system isn't under load so that tells me there might be an issue with the leveldb persistence plugin. It's native code - perhaps RHEL 6.9 isn't supported for that akka version, I'd suggest trying a newer/latest ODL version that has a newer akka version. Outside of that, unfortunately I don't have any other answers for you other than try the akka user mailing list. Or just use CentOS since that works.

Comment: Or try a later RHEL version.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your prompt responses. We will try to move to later version of Akka and check whether increasing call-timeout in akka.conf is getting honored.